# How to connect .NET with sql database?

Tags: sql-server, .net-2.0

I currently have Visual Studio 2005 and SQL Server 2005. I have installed an empty database into SQL Server, but I don't have any idea how to use VS to connect with the database.

What kind of project should I use (I'm going to use the database in a windows application) and exactly how will I be able to insert it to the project and use it?

EDIT: I have a database in Microsoft SQL Server Managament Studio, and I want to use it in a winForm, using c#. I have to connect these two somehow ?

Comment: Specify more precisely - do you need web/WinForm/console/reusable-lib project?
What language are you going use (C#/VB or report at all)?

Comment: EDIT: I have a database in Microsoft SQL Server Managament Studio, and I want to use it in a winForm, using c#. I have to connect these two somehow ?

Comment: Yeah - from the server explorer, drag a table over and a DataSource should get added to your solution. You'll then find that controls on your form with DataXXX properties will have the DataSource (your db) and Members/Values (tables/fields) available.

Answer (score 4):

You can create either of the project type:

1. Web Application
2. Windows Application
3. Console Application
4. Web Service
5. Class Library

To connect to database, use the code below:

```
SqlDataReader rdr = null;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Customers", conn);
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
conn.Close();
conn.Dispose();
```

I suggest you pick up a good book on ADO.NET and read through it. You could search for some articles on Google too.

Answer (score 2):

try this [ADO.NET Sample Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090%28VS.71%29.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

class Sample
{
  public static void Main() 
  {
    OleDbConnection nwindConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=northwind");

    OleDbCommand catCMD = nwindConn.CreateCommand();
    catCMD.CommandText = "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories";

    nwindConn.Open();

    OleDbDataReader myReader = catCMD.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
      Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", myReader.GetInt32(0), myReader.GetString(1));
    }

    myReader.Close();
    nwindConn.Close();
  }
}
```

bye

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is using ADO.Net , there is no special project to use , just use a normal Winforms Project (which you said you are already doing).

Here are some basics that you can follow http://www.sitepoint.com/article/introduction-ado-net/

Answer (score 1):

You've a few options - the easiest (but least performant, ideal, or recommended for enterprise-scale use) is via the 'Server Explorer' in Visual Studio. Accessing via View...Server Explorer... and expand Data Connections node, and browse your newly created database.

From here you can drag data sources etc onto your Windows Application.

Ideally however you'd use ADO, stored procedure or SQL directly.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio you got a Data menu option that can open a Data Sources view. Add a data connection and use the wizard to 'target' the database. After creating a local 'representation' of a table, drag that table from the datasource tab to you windows form application.

Look at all the automatically created objects and try to create a list of objects and how they interact. Can you spot the connectionstring or the table definition?

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider nHibernate or a similiar ORM.  Rather than using ADO.Net natively, the ORM layer can help reduce the amount of error prone an repetitive data access code that you right.

The learning curve is steeper than jumping into ADO.Net, but not significantly, and lots of the things you will need to learn about - relations, transactions and "business transactions", lazy loading, you will need to think about anyway - so I would suggest that being forced to think about them is no bad thing.

Checkout [www.nhforge.org](http://www.nhforge.org) for some great getting started resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DbManager
{
    
    public DbManager(string connection)
    {
        conString = connection;
    }

    public string conString, dbname;

    public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return conString;
    }

    private string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return GetConnectionString();
        }
    }

    private SqlConnection Connection { get; set; }

    private SqlCommand Command { get; set; }

    public List<DbParameter> OutParameters { get; private set; }

    private void Open()
    {
        try
        {
            Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

            Connection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }

    private void Close()
    {
        if (Connection != null)
        {
            Connection.Close();
        }
    }

    // executes stored procedure with DB parameteres if they are passed
    private object ExecuteProcedure(string procedureName, ExecuteType executeType, List<DbParameter> parameters)
    {
        object returnObject = null;

        if (Connection != null)
        {
            if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Command = new SqlCommand(procedureName, Connection);
                Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                // pass stored procedure parameters to command
                if (parameters != null)
                {
                    Command.Parameters.Clear();

                    foreach (DbParameter dbParameter in parameters)
                    {
                        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter parameter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter();
                        parameter.ParameterName = "@" + dbParameter.Name;
                        parameter.Direction = dbParameter.Direction;
                        parameter.Value = dbParameter.Value;
                        Command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                    }


                }

                switch (executeType)
                {
                    case ExecuteType.ExecuteReader:
                        SqlDataReader sdr = Command.ExecuteReader();
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        dt.Load(sdr);
                        returnObject = Command.ExecuteReader();
                        break;
                    case ExecuteType.ExecuteNonQuery:
                        returnObject = Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        break;
                    case ExecuteType.ExecuteScalar:
                        returnObject = Command.ExecuteScalar();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return returnObject;
    }

    // updates output parameters from stored procedure
    private void UpdateOutParameters()
    {
        if (Command.Parameters.Count > 0)
        {
            OutParameters = new List<DbParameter>();
            OutParameters.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < Command.Parameters.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Command.Parameters[i].Direction == ParameterDirection.Output)
                {
                    OutParameters.Add(new DbParameter(Command.Parameters[i].ParameterName,
                                                      ParameterDirection.Output,
                                                      Command.Parameters[i].Value));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // executes scalar query stored procedure without parameters
    public T ExecuteSingle<T>(string procedureName) where T : new()
    {
        return ExecuteSingle<T>(procedureName, null);
    }

    // executes scalar query stored procedure and maps result to single object
    public T ExecuteSingle<T>(string procedureName, List<DbParameter> parameters) where T : new()
    {
        Open();
        IDataReader reader = (IDataReader)ExecuteProcedure(procedureName, ExecuteType.ExecuteReader, parameters);
        T tempObject = new T();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(reader.GetName(i));
                if (propertyInfo != null)
                {
                    if (reader.GetValue(i) == DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(tempObject, null, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(tempObject, reader.GetValue(i), null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        reader.Close();

        UpdateOutParameters();

        Close();

        return tempObject;
    }

    // executes list query stored procedure without parameters
    public List<T> ExecuteList<T>(string procedureName) where T : new()
    {
        return ExecuteList<T>(procedureName, null);
    }


    public DataTable ExecuteListTable(string procedureName, List<DbParameter> parameters)
    {
        Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = (SqlDataReader)ExecuteProcedure(procedureName, ExecuteType.ExecuteReader, parameters);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(reader);
        UpdateOutParameters();
        Close();
        return dt;
    }

    // executes list query stored procedure and maps result generic list of objects
    public List<T> ExecuteList<T>(string procedureName, List<DbParameter> parameters) where T : new()
    {
        List<T> objects = new List<T>();

        Open();
        IDataReader reader = (IDataReader)ExecuteProcedure(procedureName, ExecuteType.ExecuteReader, parameters);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            T tempObject = new T();

            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                if (reader.GetValue(i) != DBNull.Value)
                {

                
                    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(reader.GetName(i));
                    if (propertyInfo != null)
                    {
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(tempObject, reader.GetValue(i), null);
                    }
                }
            }

            objects.Add(tempObject);
        }

        reader.Close();

        UpdateOutParameters();

        Close();

        return objects;
    }


    // executes non query stored procedure with parameters
    public int ExecuteNonQuery(string procedureName, List<DbParameter> parameters)
    {
        int returnValue;

        Open();

        returnValue = (int)ExecuteProcedure(procedureName, ExecuteType.ExecuteNonQuery, parameters);

        UpdateOutParameters();

        Close();

        return returnValue;
    }
    // executes scaler query stored procedure with parameters
    public string ExecuteScaler(string procedureName, List<DbParameter> parameters)
    {
        string returnValue;

        Open();

        returnValue = Convert.ToString(ExecuteProcedure(procedureName, ExecuteType.ExecuteScalar, parameters));

        UpdateOutParameters();

        Close();

        return returnValue;
    }


    private class SqlParameter
    {
        public SqlParameter()
        {
        }
    }



}

public enum ExecuteType
{
    ExecuteReader,
    ExecuteNonQuery,
    ExecuteScalar
};

public class DbParameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ParameterDirection Direction { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public SqlDbType DbType { get; set; }

    public DbParameter(string paramName, ParameterDirection paramDirection, object paramValue)
    {
        Name = paramName;
        Direction = paramDirection;
        Value = paramValue;
    }
    public DbParameter(string paramName, ParameterDirection paramDirection,SqlDbType dbType, object paramValue)
    {
        Name = paramName;
        Direction = paramDirection;
        Value = paramValue;
        dbType = DbType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

var connectionString = _dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;

```
        DbManager objDbManager = new DbManager(connectionString);
        List<DbParameter> parameters = new List<DbParameter>();
        parameters.Add(new DbParameter("COMPCODE", System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, compcode));
        parameters.Add(new DbParameter("FROMDT", System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, fromDt));
        parameters.Add(new DbParameter("TODT", System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, toDt));
        parameters.Add(new DbParameter("FILTERFROM", System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, filterFrom));
        
        DataTable dt = objDbManager.ExecuteListTable("PROC_GET_ITEMLIST", parameters);
        List<Tuple<int, string>> results = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            var tup = Tuple.Create((int)r[0], (string)r[1]);
            results.Add(tup);
        }
        return results;
```